# Applying state change to specific index of an array in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state, jsx

Yo there! Back at it again with a noob question!

So I'm fetching data from an API to render a quizz app and I'm struggling with a simple(I think) function :
I have an array containing 4 answers. This array renders 4 divs (so my answers can each have an individual div). I'd like to change the color of the clicked div so I can verify if the clicked div is the good answer later on.

Problem is when I click, the whole array of answers (the 4 divs) are all changing color.

How can I achieve that?

I've done something like that to the divs I'm rendering :

```
const [on, setOn] = React.useState(false);

  function toggle() {
    setOn((prevOn) => !prevOn);
  }

  const styles = {
    backgroundColor: on ? "#D6DBF5" : "transparent",
  };
```

I'll provide the whole code of the component and the API link I'm using at the end of the post so if needed you can see how I render the whole thing.

Maybe it's cause the API lacks an "on" value for its objects? I've tried to assign a boolean value to each of the items but I couldn't seem to make it work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

The whole component :

```
import React from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function Quizz(props) {
  const [on, setOn] = React.useState(false);

  function toggle() {
    setOn((prevOn) => !prevOn);
  }

  const styles = {
    backgroundColor: on ? "#D6DBF5" : "transparent",
  };

  function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      let temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
  }

  let answers = props.incorrect_answers;

  const ref = useRef(false);
  if (!ref.current) {
    answers.push(props.correct_answer);

    shuffleArray(answers);
    ref.current = true;
  }

  const cards = answers.map((answer, key) => (
    <div key={key} className="individuals" onClick={toggle} style={styles}>
      {answer}
    </div>
  ));

  console.log(answers);
  console.log(props.correct_answer);

  return (
    <div className="questions">
      <div>
        <h2>{props.question}</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="individuals__container">{cards}</div>
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The API link I'm using : "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=27&type=multiple"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your answers are unique in every quizz, you can use them as `id`, and instead of keeping a `boolean` value in the state, you can keep the selected answer in the state, and when you want render your `JSX` you can check the state is the same as current answer or not, if yes then you can change it's background like this:

```
function Quizz(props) {
  const [activeAnswer, setActiveAnswer] = React.useState('');
  function toggle(answer) {
    setActiveAnswer(answer);
  }
  ...
  const cards = answers.map((answer, key) => (
    <div key={key}
         className="individuals"
         onClick={()=> toggle(answer)}
         style={{background: answer == activeAnswer ? "#D6DBF5" : "transparent" }}>
         {answer}
    </div>
));
  ...
}
```

Comment: Oh my! Thanks for your quick answer man! It indeed works and it was as simple as I thought haha, I knew I did something a bit silly but I couldn't figure out what !

Thanks again and have a nice day!